# I can't found the leak , my project rootview is remove

Tags: leakcanary

[the leak image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryI6I.jpg)

I can't found the leak, the rootview is remove where destroy

Answer (score 0):

You need to override HomeCultureListFrament.onDestroyView() and set mRootView to null. The fragment views should be released in onDestroyView()